Problems calculating $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}$
I am trying to solve the following exercise:
Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$, define $f(z):=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}$.
Show that $f(z)$ exists for $|z| \neq 1$.
Attempt:
Remembering (real) Calculus my first thought was to
rewrite $\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}$ as $\frac{1-\frac{1}{z^n}}{1+\frac{1}{z^n}}$ and then argue as in the real numbers that that we get $1$ as result for $n \rightarrow \infty$.
My Problem is that, as I learned, in $\mathbb{C}$ we can't argue that way. Mainly because we can't compare complex numbers $a+ib$.
So I thought of considering the absolute valuem, |$\frac{z^n-1}{z^n+1}$|. This way I could "transport" the problem back to the real numbers.
Following my initial thought,  I am back at $\frac{|1-\frac{1}{z^n}|}{|1+\frac{1}{z^n}|}$.
So I am trying to argue that $|1-\frac{1}{z^n}|$ converges to $1 $ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.
And thats where I am stuck.

'My Problem is that, as I learned, in $\mathbb{C}$ we can't argue that way. Mainly because we can't compare complex numbers $a+ib$': It works exactly as in the real case. It is completely rigorous and the limit is $1$ for $|z|>1$, $-1$ for $|z|<1$.

Ig we have to use polar coordinates here??

you can go back to definitions and try some epsilon-n stuff on the complex function. It should work well here.

This question is similar to: How to show that the limit exists for a complex function?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. There are also other duplicates, e.g., ...

(cont.) Show the limit exists..
